# Bootstrap 3 offcanvas navigation menu size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, off-canvas-menu

I'm trying to change the size of the offcanvas navigation menu for small screens, as it's too narrow for me. I've tried changing it to col-xs-12, but it still doesn't work when toggling... 
https://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

Does anyone know how to change it?

Comment: Hi, you want a inline nav ?

Comment: Hello! Nah, not the top navbar. I'm trying to widen the vertical sidebar menu that's on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the custom CSS for the sidebar from the example to the desired width. In the example it's 50% of the screen width. To increase it to 60%..

```
.row-offcanvas-right
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    right: -60%;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    left: -60%;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-right.active {
    right: 60%; 
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 60%; 
  }

  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 60%; 
  }
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/6iCdd2Wega

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed. :)